# Mysql stored procedure insert query inside a loop only inserting last value

Tags: mysql, database, loops, stored-procedures, sql-insert

I wrote a stored procedure to insert multiple values to same table using an array and a loop. But the table only have the last value of the array. and also it is throwing an error saying

> Column can't be null.

This is my stored procedure:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `insert_images`(
packageName VARCHAR(300), 
packageUniqueCode VARCHAR(100), 
packageAddedDate DATE, 
packagePrice DOUBLE, 
packageDescription VARCHAR(3000), 
packageOwnerID INT, 
images VARCHAR(500)
)
BEGIN
    declare i INT default 0;
START TRANSACTION;
   INSERT INTO packages(packageName, packageUniqueCode, packageAddedDate, packagePrice, packageDescription, packageOwnerID) 
     VALUES(packageName, packageUniqueCode, packageAddedDate, packagePrice, packageDescription, packageOwnerID);
  SET i = 1;
   WHILE i <= JSON_LENGTH(images) DO
    INSERT INTO packageImages(imageName, location, packageOwnerID, packageID) 
    VALUES(JSON_EXTRACT(images,CONCAT( '$[', `i`, '].imageName')), JSON_EXTRACT(images,CONCAT( '$[', `i`, '].location')), packageOwnerID,LAST_INSERT_ID());
    SET i = i + 1;
   END WHILE;
COMMIT;
END
```

And I'm calling it using this code:

```
CALL insert_images("PJKG", "codea", "2022-11-11", 12, "description", 22, '[{"imageName": "pasinduImage", "location": "uploads/image"},{"imageName": "pasinduImage2", "location": "uploads/image"}]');
```

Please help me to figure things out. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON index starts from 0. So set:

```
SET i = 0;
WHILE (i < JSON_LENGTH(images)) DO
```

Comment: Thanks mate. Worked really well.